# Converting list of string into dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following continent to country

```
pd.DataFrame({'asia':[['china','india','australia']],
              'europe':[['spain','uk','russia','france','germany']],
              'americas':[['canada','usa','mexico']]
            }).transpose()
```

How do I convert into

```
asia | china
asia | india
asia | australia
europe | spain
europe | uk
```

etc.
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'asia':[['china','india','australia']],
              'europe':[['spain','uk','russia','france','germany']],
              'americas':[['canada','usa','mexico']]
            }).transpose().explode(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using explode (i.e. earlier version of Pandas)

```
(df.set_index(['index'])[0]
                    .astype(str)
                    .str.split(',', expand=True)
                    .stack()
                    .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
                    .reset_index(name='0')
            )
```